# Export blender rendered image as numpy array

Tags: python, rendering, export

I want to know the easiest way to export rendered images from blender to be exported as numpy array. 
PS: I don't want to save the images first in *.jpg or *.png and then access them. I want to directly export the rendered images as numpy array.

Comment: ...a numpy array made of what values?

Comment: Each element of the array would correspond to a pixel value of rendered image.

Comment: is is possible to render to any kind of array?

Answer (score -2):

Numpy array isn't a native output option.

Notice up at the top of the screen, when you click *Render,*
it specifies *Render Image*
[image: Render]
If you want it to directly output to a non-standard container,
you'll have to modify the source code to accomplish that.
http://download.blender.org/source/
...
You can convert standard arrays into a numpy array like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4562455/3342050
So if you don't mind running render, then using a script to export:

```
# path2numpy = '/home/me/.local/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/'   ##  linux
# path2numpy = 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\'   ##  win

import sys
sys.path.append(path2numpy)

import numpy as np
array = []

# render = bpy.ops.render.render(layer="RenderLayer", scene="Scene")
# render = bpy.data.node_groups['Compositing Nodetree'].nodes['Render Layers'].layer

array.append(render)

np_array = np.array(array)
```

The render output data is most likely going to be found in one of those commented *render* lines.
You'll have to decide which one suits your needs.

You may have to iterate through the data to get it into the necessary format.
Something along the lines of:

```
for h in range(height):
  for w in range(width):
    R = render[h][w * bpp]
    G = render[h][w * bpp + 1]
    B = render[h][w * bpp + 2]
    data.append((R,G,B))
  ''.join(data)
  array.append(data)
```

Then convert regular array to numpy array, as above.
That's all dependent upon how you want that array set up though...

Comment: You wouldn't have to alter the source code, a blender add-on could do this.

Comment: Add-ons don't bypass image generation.

Comment: Why would they want to? 'Image generation' would be part of the process of generating the values that the add-on could then export, otherwise there's nothing to export.